# Compare Range_1 to Range_2 and keep the differences in Range_1?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to compare **rng1 to rng2** and show all differences in MsgBox.
The codes works , But
I need clear all values from rng1 and keep only differences, `each difference in one cell`.
As always, your help is much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Copied_Data2()

   Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Sheets("Auto")
   Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Sheets("Closed_Items")
   
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long

    Set rng1 = Sh1.Range("A2:A22")
    
    Dim Count_rng1 As Long
     Count_rng1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng1)
    
    If Count_rng1 = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    LastRow = Sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
     Set rng2 = Sh2.Range("B" & Count_rng1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow)
  
  Dim Msg As String
   Msg = "These Item not found in sheet 'Closed_Items' : " & vbNewLine
      
  For Each A In rng1
    If Len(A.value) > 0 And Application.CountIf(rng2, A.value) = 0 Then
        Msg = Msg & A.value & vbNewLine
     End If
    Next
  Msg = Left(Msg, Len(Msg) - 2)
 MsgBox Msg
                                                                        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim v
'...
'...
For Each A In rng1
    v = A.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then 
        If Application.CountIf(rng2, v) = 0 Then
            Msg = Msg & v & vbNewLine
        Else
            A.clearcontents
        End if
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your code works , although I found a bug on my code itself.

Comment: V in your code , declared as What ?

Comment: It would be a variant